# get dynamic <td> value with $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an $.ajax() request working properly, but i need to get 4 values(name, clientid, url, id) of < td >. $.val() doesn't work, because it only works on inputs.

I need to get the name, client Id , url and id from dynamically appended rows. I need those values so, when I click on the edit button of the selected row, it saves the changes I made.

How should I get the value? with **$.html()**? **$.text()**?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 overflow-table">
                    <table class="table" id="table">
                    <thead class="head-color thead-inverse">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-left:1px solid transparent;">NAME</th>
                            <th>CLIENT-ID</th>
                            <th>URL</th>
                            <th style="border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-right:1px solid transparent;">ACTIONS</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody id='table-redirect'>
                        <tr class='lightgrey'>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='lightgrey'>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='lightgrey'>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='lightgrey'>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
            //change table content
        $(document).on('click', '#editButton', function(e) {
            var url = "http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/redirect";
            var name = $('#name1').val();
            console.log(name);
            var clientId = $('#client_id1').val();
            console.log(clientId);
            var redirectUrl = $('#url1').html();
            console.log(redirectUrl);
            var id = $('#hidden').val()
            console.log(id);
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name1', name);
            formData.append('client_id1', clientId);
            formData.append('url1', redirectUrl);
            formData.append('id', id);
            console.log('test');
            $.ajax({
                url: url + "/editRedirect",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(obj) {
                    var name, clientId, redirectUrl, id;
                    var rows = '';
                    $("tbody").empty('');
                    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        rows += "<tr class='lightgrey'><th contenteditable='true'>" + obj[i].name + "</th><td>" + obj[i].client_id + "</td><td contenteditable='true' >" + obj[i].url + "</td><td><button type='button' id='editButton' class='btn btn-info'" + obj[i].client_id + "'><img class='col-md-2 edit nopad float-right' src='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/edit.svg'></button><a href='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/click.php/?id='" + obj[i].id + "'><img class='col-md-2 link nopad float-right' src='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/copy.svg'></a></td></td></tr>";
                        console.log('sucess!');
                        console.log(obj);
                    }
                    $("#table").append(rows);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            }); //END /editRedirect $.ajax()
        }); //END $(document).on('click','#change',function(e)
```

Comment: i don't see any button with this id #editButton

Comment: It is in the success function of the ajax request `<button type='button' id='editButton' class='btn btn-info'" + obj[i].client_id + "'><img class='col-md-2 edit nopad float-right' src='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/edit.svg'></button>`

Comment: id should be unique for each element . you can use class instead of id

Comment: you have only two td with clientid and editbutton.right?

Comment: I have three `<td>`, if im not mistaken.

Comment: yes got it @Timmy

Comment: try my answer it will help you @Timmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.text()` method will return just the text within the element.

The `.html()` method will return the text, plus any HTML which might be contained within the element.

e.g. if your `<td>` looked like this for any reason:

```
<th class="clientID"><span>12345</span></th>
```

Then:

`$(".clientID").text();` will return `12345`

`$(".clientID").html();` will return `<span>12345</span>`

So for your purposes you should use `.text()` to get just the actual text content to send to the server.

You can check all this in the jQuery documentation easily, as well, and by your own tests.

Now, to get a value within the specifically clicked row, you need to restrict by the row context in the markup. In the "click" event, `this` will be the button that was clicked, which is within the `<tr>`. The corresponding data is also within the `<tr>`.

So you can use the `<tr>` as the nearest element which encloses both the button and the data. Then if you give each `<td>` a class corresponding to what it represents (client ID, url, etc) as I've done above, you can do something like:

```
var tr = $(this).closest("tr"); //get the parent tr
var clientID = tr.find(".clientID").text(); //get the client ID text within the tr
var url = tr.find(".url").text(); //same for url, etc...
```

Lastly, your button clicks won't work properly because you're duplicating IDs. It will only ever work for the first button.

Change `<button type='button' id='editButton' class='btn btn-info'` to `<button type='button' class='btn btn-info editButton'` (use a class instead of an id)

and change `$(document).on('click', '#editButton', function(e) {` to `$(document).on('click', '.editButton', function(e) {` (simply, `#` is changed to `.`)

Comment: Very complete and easy to understand! Thank you so much for your help :) (every answer helped)

Answer (score 1):

1) you appending multiple row with duplicate id . id should be unique for each element . just use class name instead of id .

2) appending one th   and extra td

```
<th contenteditable='true'>" + obj[i].name + "</th>
```

Updated code with class name

```
`   <tr class='lightgrey'>
    <td contenteditable='true' class="name">" + obj[i].name + "</td>
    <td class="client_id">" + obj[i].client_id + "</td>
    <td contenteditable='true' class="url" >" + obj[i].url + "</td>
    <td>
    <button type='button'  class='btn btn-info editButton'" + obj[i].client_id + "'>
    <img class='col-md-2 edit nopad float-right' src='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/edit.svg'>
    </button><a href='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/click.php/?id='" + obj[i].id + "'>
    <img class='col-md-2 link nopad float-right' src='http://mobisteinlp.com/redirect/public/img/copy.svg'></a>
    </td>
    </tr>`
```

Jquery :

Setup class name for each td and traverse and access it easily like this

```
  `$(document).on('click', '.editButton', function(e) {

        var tr = $(this).closest("tr"); 
        var client_id = tr.find(".client_id").text();
        var url = tr.find(".url").text(); 
        var name = tr.find(".name").text(); 

    });`
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the different between these commands, then you can fix your by yourself
The following used to retreive data from a value attribute(normally input tags).

//Here id is id name of your element

```
$('#id').val();
```

If you want to get the data from a element you need to use

1. This will return the text inside the element.

```
$('#id').text()
```

2. This will return the html inside the element.

```
$('#id').html()
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: There is no id with name of id @Kuru

Comment: @Timmy don't get hung up on the exact selector used, this is just a generic example of the difference between .text and .html

Answer (score -1):

Try It...

```js
$("#ObjectsTable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(arr, function(index,value) {
  $('#ObjectsTable')
        .append($("<tr>" +
              "<td>" + value.ID + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + value.Model + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + value.Type + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + value.Color + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + value.Price + "</td>" +
              "</tr>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ObjectsTable" class="responstable">
 <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Model</th>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Color</th>
  <th>Price</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The question is about _retreiving_ values from the td, not _appending_ them. I agree this is a nicer way to generate the new rows than raw string concatenation, but it doesn't answer the question. Also, it would be more helpful if the code reflected the OP's actual fields, rather than a generic example